# Sync Android Memo with Evolution Memo

Tags: android, evolution

The title sums it up. Right now I know I can sync my Android memos with a Gmail account. It puts them in a Notes folder (aka a label) on Gmail. But now Im unsure how to go from gmail to Evolution.

Evolution gives me two options in the Memo list creation. I can either do "CalDAV" and input a server, user, path or do "On The Web" with a URL and a username.

Any easy way to do this? Im thinking to find a static URL to my notes folder in gmail as something I can use for creating a Memo list in Evolution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I tried the On The Web option whilst creating a memo list in Evolution and added my gmail notes folder (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#label/Notes) and also inputed my email address. After clicking OK to create the memo list it asks for my gmail password and all seems OK. But it never fills in my Evolution Memo list with the memos (emails) from my Gmail Notes folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a android phone. But I could sync my Bada OS 2 phone with Evolution over funambol. It syncs memo, tasks, calendar and contacts.

I used this german tutorial: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Funambol